# Finite model property and pseudofiniteness

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

A logic $L$ has the finite model property if for every formula $\phi$ of $L$, $\phi$ is an $L$-theorem iff $\phi$ is a theorem of the theory of finite models of $L$.

A structure $M$ is called pseudofinite if $M\models \phi$, then there a finite structure $M_0$ such that $M_0\models \phi$.

Question: What is the different between the finite model property and pseudo-finiteness? I'm confused by their definitions!

Comment: Well, the first is a property of a logic, and the second is a property of a structure. That's a pretty clear difference. Can you elaborate on what is confusing you, or what more you're looking for?

Comment: @AlexKruckman both of them refers to the existence of a finite model s.t. ...., right? So my maybe my question is this: what is the relation between these two concepts?